# Wrtie to ssh's stdin from another process

Tags: ssh

I have ssh connection where I want to perform some actions with pauses, but there is no ability to write a script for this system. My idea was to write to `/proc/<pid>/fd/0` but unfortunately this doesn't work (letters appear in ssh terminal, but don't change anything).

Is there any way to perform such actions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like `cat input.txt | ssh target.yourdomain.com " ./process"`?

```
petr@d1:~$ echo "hello" | ssh myuser@myserver "cat"
hello
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I need to add a pause between commands. And there is no `sleep` command